# Let $n\times n$ matrices $A,B$ satsify $A^2=A, B^2=B, (A+B)^2=A+B$, show $AB=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $n\times n$ matrices $A,B$ satsify $A^2=A, B^2=B, (A+B)^2=A+B$, show $AB=0$.

I know just $AB+BA=0$. What to do next?

Comment: From $AB=-BA$ we obtain $AB=AAB=A(-BA)=-ABA$. From $BA=-AB$ we also obtain $BA=BAA=(-AB)A=-ABA$. Hence $AB=BA$.

Comment: Which brings up the question: what if the scalar field has characteristic 2?  And in that case, you have a counterexample $A = B = I_n$ which satisfies the hypotheses but $AB \ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$A^2=A$
$BA^2=BA$
$A^2B=-AB$
$AB=-AB$
$2AB=0$

Comment: Can you please explain the $2^\text{nd}$ to $3^\text{rd}$ step?

Comment: @PCMSE $BA^2=-ABA=-A(-AB)=A^2B$

Comment: Yes got it. Thank you very much @cineel